# Push notification fundamentals

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to implement like this http://dotnettrain.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/push-notifications-in-windows-phone-75.html

I am sending and receiving in the same page. A.xaml

The Payload I am trying to send :In  GetToastPayLoad

```
string message = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
     "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
      "<wp:Toast>" +
       "<wp:Text1>New Link Request</wp:Text1>" +
       "<wp:Text2>"+data.Title+"</wp:Text2>" +
      "</wp:Toast>" +
     "</wp:Notification>";
```

And the header for httpRequest is :-

```
  .........................................
   var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(channelUri));
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                payload = GetToastPayload(data);
                request.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
                request.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");
                }
```

I am able to capture the response in A.xaml as OnToastNotificationReceived and print in the details in a message box.

But when I remove the event handler, I am not getting any notification in my running application.

**How can I receive and display in proper manner as a normal toast notification?**

***What should I do to make this universal, say I want it to be displayed wherever the user is: A.xaml, B.xaml, C.xaml *etc.* ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive notifications anywhere try to put your code inside the `App()` constructor in `App.xaml.cs` as it is showed in [Sending toast notifications on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/sending-toast-notifications)

Toast notifications are not showed when your app is running so you won't be able to show them this way (even if you try to manually execute [ToastPrompt](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth)) So you should use [ShellToastNotificationReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.shelltoastnotificationreceived%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to handle notifications in this case.

When your app is not running you should see toast notifications showed.